# Vim not loading plugins

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, vundle

For some reason my vim is not loading any plugins at all. I am using Vundle to manage plugins. All the plugins are installed in default location (ie. `~/.vim/bundle`). I tried re-installing Vundle, but the issue still persists. Here's how my `.vimrc` file looks like:

```
" System vimrc file for MacVim

set nocompatible
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
" Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
"my modifs"
imap jj <Esc>
set nu
set clipboard=unnamed
map <C-j> <C-e><C-e><C-e>
map <C-k> <C-y><C-y><C-y>
set tags=./tags;/

" The default for 'backspace' is very confusing to new users, so change it to a
" more sensible value.  Add "set backspace&" to your ~/.vimrc to reset it.
set backspace+=indent,eol,start

" Disable localized menus for now since only some items are translated (e.g.
" the entire MacVim menu is set up in a nib file which currently only is
" translated to English).
set langmenu=none

" Python2
" MacVim uses Homebrew python2 if installed, otherwise configured one
if exists("&pythondll") && exists("&pythonhome")
  if filereadable("/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python")
    " Homebrew python 2.7
    set pythondll=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
    set pythonhome=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
  endif
endif

" Python3
" MacVim uses Homebrew python3 if installed, next try to use python.org binary
if exists("&pythonthreedll") && exists("&pythonthreehome") &&
      \ !filereadable(&pythonthreedll)
  if filereadable("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python")
    " https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/
    set pythonthreedll=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python
    set pythonthreehome=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5
  endif
endif
```

I am using MacVim on macOS 10.12 if it matters. This is what `vim --version` spits out:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr  5 2017 00:31:23)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-525
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+arabic          +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+autocmd         +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+balloon_eval    -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+browse          +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
++builtin_terms  +fullscreen      -mzscheme        +textobjects
+byte_offset     -gettext         +netbeans_intg   +timers
+channel         -hangul_input    +num64           +title
+cindent         +iconv           +odbeditor       +toolbar
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +transparency
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -framework CoreFoundation -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -framework Ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.vimrc` file looks like the sample `.vimrc` from https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

Actually you have to add the plugins you want in the `.vimrc`

For my case this looks like:

```
filetype off 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
  Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
  Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
  Plugin 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
  Plugin 'itchyny/calendar.vim'
  Plugin 'aaronbieber/vim-quicktask.git'
  Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
  Plugin 'ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim.git'
  Plugin 'tmhedberg/matchit'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

For each plugin you like, you should add a line like `Plugin 'name/gitrepo'`
After that you have to install the Plugins you could do this directly out of the terminal with:

```
 vim +PluginInstall +qall
```

You have to have git installed.

Comment: All the plugins are already installed. Yes I have taken contents from Vundle's repo. But it still has some plugins like fugitive and I'm expecting them to work.

Comment: I tried with adding `Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'` to my `.vimrc`. After `vim +PluginInstall +qall` I had downloaded content in `.vim\bundle\vim-fugitive`. So actually I think it should work; myself I don't know vim-fugitive, so I don't know how to test. But I think you have to have a look at https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive to finish the configuration and to have full profit of this plugin.