# vim not loading plugins using the native plugin manager

Tags: vim

For some reason vim is not loading plugins. How to diagnose this problem in a proper manner? I am using the native plugin manager. [I found a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479647/vim-not-loading-plugins) that is related to Vundle but I am trying the native manager. There are no errors so I think none of the packages were not loaded. The platform is Linux.

The vim version is:
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct  3 2019 13:18:48)
Included patches: 1-2109

And plugin folder structure is :

```
.vim
├── after
│   └── syntax
├── colors
└── pack
    └── bundle
        └── start
            ├── ack
            ├── FuzzyFinder
            ├── jedi-vim
            ├── l9
            └── python-mode
```

Vim was compiled with package support:
vim --version | grep packages
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar

Comment: `:help package` is **not** a "native plugin manager". Also, what makes you think those plugins are not loaded?

Comment: What is the output of `$ vim --version | grep packages`?

Comment: @romainl added the answer.. The packages were not loaded because ack does not work inside vim and I get `E492: Not an editor command: Ack`

Comment: What have you tried to do? Clearly something involving Ack. What plugins did you try install and what guides / steps have you followed?